# How to count similar array keys using PHP?

Tags: php, count, array-key

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     $count = count(preg_grep("/^options(\d)+$/", array_keys(get_object_vars($value))));
     echo $count; exit;
```

`echo $count` is giving 0.

If I do `print_r($value);exit;`, the `$value` variable is giving this result:

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection Object
(
    [title:protected] => 
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [question_set] => Computer Basics
            [question] => Who are You ?
            [options1] => RK
            [options2] => KAMAL
            [options3] => DPK
            [options4] => NARENDRA
            [marks] => 5
            [negative_marks] => 1
            [type] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to calculate keys options1, options2 so on because these options are dynamic. How can I do this?

Comment: sorry i didn't mention one minute i update

Comment: shouldn't you be looking at `$value->items`? also, since that's protected, maybe the class has a function that returns the contents of `items`? (a getter)

Comment: ok @rid let me check if it will work or not

Comment: You can calculate the similarity of two strings with similar_text function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more @RogerWayne